# How to print h1 value back in html with a range?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a range in my html.....
Now my problem is that I want to print the value of the range back in my
html

This is the html for my range

```
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
<input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100">                                                       

    <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
    </form>
```

And i have a button to confirm the value

```
<div id="bevestig">
    <h1>Bevestig</h1>
</div>
```

Has anyone an idea how to print the value of the range back in my html after you click on the h1?

Comment: can you add a fiddle please...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9q3839wc/

Comment: Do you know how to create functions and set event listeners?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add some javascript to accomplish this.

```js
document.getElementById("bevestig").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('rangeInput');
    var output = document.getElementById('results');
    output.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<form onchange="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
    <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
    <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
</form>
<div id="bevestig">
    <h1>Bevestig</h1>
</div>
<p id="results"></p>
```